They sold me a useless SIM card at Bali airport. What can I do?
I got a Smartfren SIM card in Bali airport for 300,000 IDR. It has no signal most of the time and absolutly useless. Is there anythings I can do?

What exact phone model do you have? Note that for instance many iPhones have different variants with different band support.

Did you ever get a signal? Indonesia requires registration first to whitelist the device: How to register IMEI in Indonesia (read the "Tourist Registration" section)

@jcaron it's about the week signal and not the phone model.

@AndrewT. yes, it worked in the airport itself.

@RealDreams It can be a phone issue if your phone doesn't support the same bands that SmartFren usually uses. What's your model and where did you buy it?

@RealDreams you may not know that 4G involves dozens of different bands and many different technologies, with all carriers only using a very small subset of them, and many (most?) phones only supporting a subset of them, with the subset possibly being different depending on where you bought the phone. You can then end up in a situation where your specific phone only has limited support for the bands of the carrier involved, which reduces coverage and/or performance.

It seems I can't do much and the money is wasted. https://flip.id/en/blog/cellular-provider-in-indonesia

The smallest and cheapest mobile service provider Indonesia is
Smartfren. It was previously a CDMA mobile provider, but has since
switched to a GSM 4G/LTE network. Today, Smartfren is a 4G/LTE-only
mobile operator because it lacks a 2G or 3G network. Consequently,
Smartfren has the least coverage since it’s a 4G/LTE mobile operator
without a 2G or 3G fallback. However, you can receive service if you
live in major cities.

I reached out to their customer service team, and they rejected a refund too.

Note that the 4G coverage of all providers is roughly similar (you can compare at https://www.gsma.com/coverage/#848), but others do indeed have 2G/3G coverage in addition to 4G. But while 2G/3G are OK to make calls, they are of very limited use for anything data-related nowadays.

Indonesian consumer laws do not allow for refunds unless the product is defective etc. Smartfren is Indonesia's 4th largest operator and has 35M million subscribers, so they're legit, I don't think you have any grounds for a refund.
As for why you've having trouble, are you in their coverage area? They cover most major cities but Indonesia is a very large place.

Were you able to actually use the coverage map on their site? It's completely buggy here...

Another issue may be your phone's compatibility with the carrier wireless bands
Smartfen uses 4G LTE bands B5 (850) and B40 (TDD 2300)
You can check it on Kimovil (not affiliated)

The OP said they don't get signal most of the time, so it's unlikely just a phone issue.

@littleadv Most towers will only broadcast one band, so if the phone is not compatible with that one band, it will not get any signal

@littleadv Nicolas is correct, this can be a phone issue if the bands don't match.  Rare with 4G, but not unheard for, particularly with US models.

These comments should be incorporated into the answer to make it useful

It's not a phone issue.

@RealDreams What makes you so sure? It has the exact typical symptoms of an incompatibility in supported frequency bands. When the carrier uses bands A, B, C but your phone supports A, D, E, you will only see a signal when you happen to be in a cell that runs on A and get no reception otherwise. Exactly the behaviour you describe.
